# catch json response in jquery using ajax without refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5

I am missing something...but i don`t know what. I want to make an ajax request using jquery and laravel 5.4. In java script i have

```
    function changeUserPassword(){

    var current_pasword = $('input[name="current_password"]').val();
    var new_password = $('input[name="new_password"]').val();
    var confirm_password = $('input[name="confirm_password"]').val();

    if(new_password === confirm_password){

        $.ajax({
            url: $('#changePsw_form').attr('action'),
            type: 'POST',
            data: {current_pasword: current_pasword, new_password:new_password, confirm_password: confirm_password},
            success: function(response){
                var resp = JSON.parse(response);
                alert(resp.message);
            },
            error: function(response){
                var resp = JSON.parse(response);               
                alert(resp.message);
            }
        });
    }
    else{
        alert('Password don`t match!');
    }
}

 $('#savePsw').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    changeUserPassword();
 });
```

My html form is

```
<div class="row" id="changePsw">
    <form method="post" class="form-horizontal" id="changePsw_form" action="{{ route('changepassword') }}">
        <div class="form-group col-md-12 has-feedback">
            <label class="control-label col-md-4 col-md-pull-1" for="password">Current Password:
            </label>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="current_password">
                <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" id="password_icon"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-12 has-feedback">
            <label class="control-label col-md-4 col-md-pull-1" for="new_password">New Password:
            </label>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="new_password" name="new_password">
                <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" id="new_password_icon"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-12 has-feedback">
            <label class="control-label col-md-4 col-md-pull-1" for="confirm_password">Confirm password:
            </label>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirm_password" name="confirm_password">
                <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" id="confirm_password_icon"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-success" id="savePsw">Save</button>
        {{ csrf_field() }}
    </form>
</div>
```

In my script i tried to check if the password match but is not. It goes directly to post url and get response from server (laravel controller) in browser (plain json)

```
 return response()->json(['success' => false, 'message' => 'Password don`t match!']);

{"success":false,"message":"Password don`t match!"}
```

Why it fails that if:

```
 if(new_password === confirm_password)
```

How to check (on client) if password match? (then do the ajax) How to catch the response and showing in alert? (not plain json in browser) WITHOUT REFRESH???

Comment: Why did @meagar make this [on hold]? I think my problem was clear: - yes my english is not so good but...i was trying to say: .How to check (on client) if two input fields match? (then do the ajax) - in other CLEAR words: How can i check if the input values are equals, if there are -> do the ajax else show a message and do nothing! I don`t know what i did wrong in my script.

Comment: You need to include all the relevant code **in the question**, not on some external code-hosting service.

Comment: i thought is much cleaner using code-hosting like kopy or something similar

Comment: That's expressly against the rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify dataType of your response.

```
$.ajax({
dataType: 'json',
...
```

Also, it's good way to figure out what's going on using console.log in your success method:

```
success: function(response){
 if(response.success == true){
    //Write code here is success
    console.log("success code here");
 }
 else{
   console.log(response.message);
 }
}
```

**EDIT**

adding onclick to the button:

```
onclick="submit"
```

and:

```
onsubmit="changeUserPassword()"
```

to the FORM works!

The js should be:

```
    function changeUserPassword(){

    var current_pasword = $('input[name="current_password"]').val();
    var new_password = $('input[name="new_password"]').val();
    var confirm_password = $('input[name="confirm_password"]').val();

    if($('#changePsw_form').valid()){
        if(new_password === confirm_password){
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: $('#changePsw_form').attr('action'),
                type: 'POST',
                data: {current_pasword: current_pasword, new_password:new_password, confirm_password: confirm_password},
                dataType: 'JSON',
                success: function(response){
                    if(response.success){
                        swal('Success!', response.message, 'success');
                    }
                    else{
                        swal('Failed!', response.message, 'error');
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        else{
            event.preventDefault();
            swal('Password Mismatch!', "Please try again!", "warning");
        }
    }
}
```